# Jquery $.when with multiple parameters and xhr

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using $.when with multiple request. Please consider the code below:

```
$.when(
    $.ajax({url: '/show/' + showId + '/details.json', type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', async: false}),
    $.ajax({url: '/show/' + showId + '/graphicAssets.json', type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', async: false}),
    $.ajax({url: '/graphicAssets/show/' + showId + '/files.json', type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', async: false}),
    $.ajax({url: '/graphicAssets/show/types.json', type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', async: false}),
    $.ajax({url: '/season/'+ showId +'/seasons.json', type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', async: false}),
    $.ajax({url: '/freebie/' + showId + '/freebies.json', type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', async: false})
)
.then(function(showDetailsData, showGraphicAssetsData, showFilesData, showTypesData, showSeasonsData, showFreebieData, status, xhr) {
    if (xhr.status == '302') location.reload();

    // Rest of the code goes here
}
```

Now, what I want to do is to check the response status from the xhr object. The result is undefined. How can I resolve this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass multiple deferreds to `$.when`, the `then` handler receives an array containing results of resolving each deferred. So in your case you'll get 7 arrays each containing `data, textStatus, jqXHR`.

Hence in your case, the correct usage would be something like:

```
$.when(
$.ajax({url: '/show/' + showId + '/details.json', type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', async: false}),
$.ajax({url: '/show/' + showId + '/graphicAssets.json', type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', async: false}),
$.ajax({url: '/graphicAssets/show/' + showId + '/files.json', type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', async: false}),
$.ajax({url: '/graphicAssets/show/types.json', type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', async: false}),
$.ajax({url: '/season/'+ showId +'/seasons.json', type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', async: false}),
$.ajax({url: '/freebie/' + showId + '/freebies.json', type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', async: false})
)
.then(function(showDetailsData, showGraphicAssetsData, showFilesData, showTypesData, showSeasonsData, showFreebieData) {
    if (showDetailsData[2].status == '302' 
        || showGraphicAssetsData[2].status == '302' 
        ... etc) location.reload();

    // Rest of the code goes here
}
```

Comment: Great! I was about to answer my question, but you went ahead. Here's an accept. :)